# Cannot import rates from a web page?

Tags: google-sheets-formula, importerror

I'm using importxml to get a rate to my spreadsheet to get it automatically, but I encountered the following error, after I select Vietnam from 送金をする相手国:, then I hovered over the rate e.g 197.xxx VND, then mouse-right click select "Inspect" and paste it in the sheet.

=IMPORTXML("http://smileswallet.com/simulator/","/html/body/ion-app/ng-component/ion-nav/page-main/ion-content/div[2]/div/div[3]/ul/div/div[1]/label/div/text()")

but I get: "Error, the imported content is empty"

is there any problem with the function? how can I get the rates to be imported to my "google spreadsheet"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Javscript rendered content is not supported by `IMPORTXML`

Comment: Is there any other import command to retrieve this data?